# Why StackOverflowError occuring in android android.text.TextUtils.getChars?

Tags: java, android

In my application this error is occurring multiple time. How to avoid this?

I found some answers that say , its due to using multiple layer. But not clear with concept of multiple layer.

```
0   java.lang.StackOverflowError
1   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
2   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1328)
3   at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:651)
4   at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4328)
5   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6985)
6   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
7   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
8   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
9   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
10  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
11  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
12  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
13  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6710)
14  at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6490)
15  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1657)
16  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
17  at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1499)
18  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3194)
19  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
20  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2607)
21  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
22  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
23  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
24  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
25  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
26  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
27  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
28  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
29  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
30  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
31  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
32  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
33  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
34  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
35  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
36  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
37  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
38  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
39  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
40  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
41  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
42  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
43  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
44  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
45  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
46  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
47  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
48  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
49  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
50  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
51  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
52  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
53  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
54  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
55  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
56  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
57  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
58  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
59  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
60  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
61  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6988)
62  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
63  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
64  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1602)
65  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1323)
66  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1961)
67  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
68  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
69  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
70  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
71  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
72  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
73  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
74  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: +1 for StackOverflowError question on StackOverflow.  -1 for not including the code where the error occurs.

Comment: @Gibron: I just put the whole stack-trace here. You can see there is not a single class / method list from my application code , but only the android code is here. So I don't know what code need to share :)
I am can't share code for my whole application.

Comment: I agree with the OP, the stack trace tells everything necessary in this case.

Comment: @Arslan insight into your architecture will only help others help you.    If you cant provide code, provide more info that could be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the stack trace, it looks like you have a very deep widget nesting structure! That is the cause of the stack overflow, not so much the `getChars`. If you can, consider simplifying your widget tree, so widgets aren't so deeply nested.

Comment: In my application I have a group activity used as tab activity, and all the other activities open in that layout. As each activity has its own layout. the max activities which can be open in one tab are 4-6. Is that might cause problem?

Comment: Wait, it seems from the stack trace that your layout is much more complicated than you're explaining here. It appears to me that your widgets are at least 25 levels deep!

Comment: Ok , Thanks I check my application in more detail to avoid this.

Comment: Is there any tool available to check for Stack-trace?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. What do you want this tool to do?